# Spring application database row level security best approach

Tags: sql, database, spring

What is the best approach to implement **row level security** in spring web application and its database? I have many tables which contain application users data. User can select, update and delete only his own rows. User is defined in table in database and logs to application with spring-security. I am using one database account to connect from application to database.

My idea is to create column with username in every table (do i need relationships here?). Now I can just add `'where username = <username>'` in backend queries. Is it good idea? What is most common approach in cases like this?

I manage data access with JPA and Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define an owner for every object you need to validate. You can validate the user in the database with a where clause.

But you can also add another layer in the method with Spring @PostFilter. It lets you filter the returning object.

@PostFilter ("filterObject.owner == authentication.name")
public List getMyObjects();

You can see more here.

http://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-security/prefilter-postfilter-in-spring-security

Comment: It will filter on the application side only, you can have performance problems, once you will fetch everything (depending your where clause) from the database before filter. Better to go to another solution that filter on the database where clause (using JPA, Spring Data or any other solution).

Answer (score 0):

Some databases already have row level security feature. Oracle offer Virtual Private Database, PostreSQL have `alter table ... enable row level security;`. SQL server has this feature too. In other databases you have to do all work manually (via auxiliary column in table or/and special check in wrapper view): [question about mysql on SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105052/mysql-user-row-level-access), [MairaDB](https://mariadb.com/blog/protect-your-data-row-level-security-mariadb-100).