# clarifying handling users Mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Im new to mysql and after watching alot of videos there are some things about users i dont get.

edit :
When i create a new user using Mysql workbench i can only assign username, password and privileges. Is this new user what a customer will use to login in the database ? if so, where is the table that contains this user username and password ? can I add columns like email, fullname, points to this table ? if i cant am i suppose to add the new user username to my own "Customer Table" and add all the new columns i need there ?

Is that how Im suppose to handle new users and their info or am i missing something?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here ..  Are you asking here How to do [MySQL user row level based access/privileges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105052/mysql-user-row-level-access)

Comment: Hi, no i rewrote the question. hope is clear now. thank you